# Can someone please explain this code snippet

Tags: android, sqlite

when I try to open the web browser (from home in Kindle fire HD) and it just plain fails to launch.
I checked the device logs and could find below exception:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 29 to 27

I googled the exception and could find the following code snippet is throwing this exception. Could some one please explain clearly about this. And what I need to do for this

```
try {
             mIsInitializing = true;
             String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(mName).getPath();
             db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, mFactory, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY,
                     mErrorHandler);
             if (db.getVersion() != mNewVersion) {
                 throw new SQLiteException("Can't upgrade read-only database from version " +
                         db.getVersion() + " to " + mNewVersion + ": " + path);
             }
```

Comment: can some one please explain

Comment: We don't see where mNewVersion is set, but the error is saying (very poorly) that the version of SQLite on your emulator or android device is 2 versions higher than the expected version.

Comment: Not SQLite, but the database version. Just wipe the cached data of your browser in settings->manage applications and it should be fine.

Comment: @thibaultd why I need to wipe the cached data of my browser settings. Can you please explain it clearly. Other than that is there any work around for this?

Comment: sqlite stores a version number for the database which can be set once when creating the database. afterwards you can change the version but one of the two methods onUpgrade or onDowngrade will get called. you should clear the cache because then it will clear the database and you can create a new database without worrying about the version conflicts.

Comment: @SaeidFarivar so once i clear the cache data, when i re open the browser it will call new database version rite?

Comment: I would assume so. I am not familiar with Kindle thu, I have used sqlite for android and that's what happens.

Comment: @SaeidFarivar sorry for asking. Can you explain a bit more clearly. So here SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase operation calling latest database version but the silk browser is in old version. So that's why we are getting this error rite? so wiping of the data clear the database versions and it will create newest version of database rite

Comment: other than clearing cache data is there any work around for this? I mean is there any code change required?

Comment: clearing data will work. But i want other options

Comment: the workaround would be removing the line of code that is throwing the error which is throw new sqliteexception ... ! :) 
you're right, you're getting the error because the versions doen't match.

Comment: Thanks for patient replies

Answer (score 0):

private final int mNewVersion;

public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version,
                  DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
              if (version < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be >= 1, was " + version);
              if (errorHandler == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("DatabaseErrorHandler param value can't be null.");
              }

```
          mContext = context;
          mName = name;
          mFactory = factory;
          mNewVersion = version;
          mErrorHandler = errorHandler;
     }
```

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc. you can find from above code where mNewVersion is set

Answer (score 0):

You could give a bit more context, especially since Kindle products are running a fork of Android.

Regarding sources I was only able to find tarballs:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200203720&tag=viglink121875-20

How did you get to the source code shown above (link please)?

The code says that it is not prepared to support upgrades between different database versions at all.

What it would have to do in your scenario is upgrade from version 29 to 27, which would be a downgrade.